# Azure Pipelines Schedule to Run Only Few Days a Month

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to customize the pipeline scheduling options in Azure to have it run only the second week of each month?

I know you can schedule it to run on individual days of the week, but I cannot figure out how I would do this on a monthly scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I do this if my pipeline was made as a classic/GUI based, and not
> as a YAML pipeline?

In the classic pipelines, you can only set scheduled triggers for each week. As far as I know, you can not have it run only the second week of each month in the classic pipelines. However, you can set schedule triggers in yaml pipeline and use it to trigger your classic pipeline.

Here is the sample if you are going to use a YAML pipeline:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 8-14 * *" 
  displayName: schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true
```

In this example:

- The pipeline will be triggered from the 8th to the 14th of this
  month. You need to update the date each month.
- `always: true` means [run even when there are no code changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#running-even-when-there-are-no-code-changes).
- Agree with iikkoo that if you want to run your pipeline by **only using scheduled triggers**, you must disable PR and continuous integration triggers by specifying pr: none and trigger: none in your YAML file.
- You can add a build completion trigger in this yaml pipeline to trigger your classic pipeline:
  [image][image]

Please find more detailed information about [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the document.

Comment: Note: if you want the pipeline ONLY to trigger by the cron schedule, don't forget to set trigger:none and pr:none in your yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by creating a scheduling trigger in your YAML config. Note tough, you must disabled PR and CI triggers to run your pipeline by using scheduled triggers.

You disable the trigger by setting `pr: none` and `trigger: none`. Then you define the schedule using cron syntax.

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 1/14 * *" # At 00:00 on every 14th day-of-month from 1 through 31.
  displayName: Second week of each month
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    ...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/Crontab-Expression

https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Can I do this if my pipeline was made as a classic/GUI based, and not as a YAML pipeline? I'm new to all this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, but note that "Scheduled triggers defined using the pipeline settings UI take precedence over YAML scheduled triggers.".

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to do so in the UI, but you can still trigger the build via an API call on your own schedule.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1